# sudo command make child process to zombies

Tags: sudo, process, c, monitoring, execute-command

I'm trying to make a program that divides into child and parent processes with `fork()`. Child executes arguments with `execv()` and parent traces him with `ptrace()`. I made almost all parts of the program, but `sudo` command arguments.

For example, when I write command `./my_program apt-get update`, it works well.
When I write command `./my_program sudo apt-get update`, command output sticks at "Reading state information... Done" and stops. If I terminate it with `Ctrl C`, It turns into a zombie process.
Also, `stace ./my_program sudo apt-get update` does not work, but `stace -f ./my_program sudo apt-get update` works well.

Is there any way to deal with this error by editing C codes? not commands like `kill -9`?

environments

- Docker(Windows)
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- files in /home/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use strace and ptrace over security boundaries like what is created with sudo.  Allowing that would create a very large security hole.

If you really need to do this, you will need to run the ptrace/strace after the sudo so that both processes are in the same security context.

Zombie processes are mostly harmless and exist because the parent process (for whatever reason) hasn't noticed that the child exited.  They should go away if the parent calls wait() or exits itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already did `sudo ./my_program sudo apt-get update` but it didn't work too :(  
Also I used wait() on parent but parent cannot catch child's exit(). Is this the security problem you said?

Comment: Don't use sudo twice, there's no point in it, and by doing that, you *still* have a security barrier.

Comment: Okay. now I get it. Thank you. :)